# Fix firebase auth session expire in 1hr

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an android app using firebase as database.There is a searchview will appear after authentication.But.,the data could n't be load after 1 hr from firebase due to the session expired.How can i fix this problem.?

Comment: If you're using the Firebase Auth SDK, it should refresh the token every hour automatically.  If you're not using the Firebase SDKs, that's something you'd have to do on your own.

Comment: how can i do it.? do you have any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

the authentication mechanism for google services are based on OAuth. In this mechanism you are given 1 token with which you can create session tokens, and each session token will last for 1 hour. this means that you must automatically create new session tokens if your session expires. google already provides good libraries for popular languages.

Comment: How can i create token automatically..?

Comment: Did you do any tutorials ? something like this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Comment: This is not enough for my problem.